# Изменение переменной в зависимости от экрана на JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

Использую [bootstrap-table.js](https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/blob/develop/src/bootstrap-table.js) 
Хочу изменить вид отображения таблицы на мобильных устройствах, но если использую следующий код

```
    cardView: $(window).resize(function() {
      if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 670) {
        return false;
      } else {return true;}
    }),
```

(326 строка в bootstrap-table.js), по умолчанию отображается cardView: true, независимо от экрана

По умолчанию код имеет вид

```
cardView: false,
```

Пример где я использую [здесь](http://demos.creative-tim.com/fresh-bootstrap-table)

Comment: я даже не могу словами верно описать то что у вас в коде написано ) 
повесте обработчик события на ресайз гдето отдельно и внутри его уже меняйте нужную вам переменную

Comment: Было бы не плохо пример кода, и мы вам так быстрей поможем

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эм, а может просто юзать родной метод удобнее?

Вот обработчик, вешается на resize и меняет вид карточки в зависимости от ширины window

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
      if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 670) {
        $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions',{cardView:false})
      } else {
        $table.bootstrapTable('refreshOptions',{cardView:true})
      }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло! Всё дело в refreshOptions.

Answer (score 1):

`$(window).resize(function() {})` привязывает к событию изменения размера экрана функцию, но он не возвращает её результат при каждом изменении размера, вместо этого он (точнее она — это функция) возвращает объект (а т.к. объект преобразуется в `true` то у вас и вылезает вот такая "проблема").

В вашем случае нужно сделать нечто такое (с указанной вами библиотекой не знаком, времени разбираться не было):

```js
$(window).resize(function() {
    var cardView;
    if(document.documentElement.clientWidth > 670) {
        cardView = false;
    } else {
        cardView = true;
    }
    BootstrapTable.DEFAULTS.cardView = cardView;
});
```

Comment: Спасибо! Стало более понятно, как это реализуется. Я пока только в начале пути изучения.